# Can I rewrite Javascript without using 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm very new to JS and I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Here is my code

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').each(function() {
jQuery(this).removeClass('current-menu-item');
jQuery(this).removeClass('current_page_item');
});
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current_page_item');
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Now what this *should* be doing is remove the highlight from one link on a navigation menu, and highlighting the one thats been clicked (I have an AJAX implementation).

For some reason it isn't doing anything. I have a feeling it is due to 'this' is there another way of structuring this code so I can work out if the code is wrong, which I don't believe it to be, or because of 'this'?

EDIT:

Apologies, it seems I haven't given enough information. I'm using the Twenty Fourteen wordpress theme but I'm serving the pages with AJAX.

http://twentyfourteendemo.wordpress.com/

I have the code being applied globally (I have other code in the same place to toggle the navigation once clicked (on mobile) and that works fine)

I have the menu at the top (without any dropdowns, just links). I can't give a link as it's not external currently. Should my code be working to change this?

As a few people have commented "What is 'this'" I feel I've completely missed something.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: you need to share more context to the problem

Comment: Unrelated note in case you're unaware: instead of `jQuery` you can also use `$` -- eg: `$("ul.menu li")` (assuming `$` isn't overloaded by something else).

Comment: you can shorten this to `jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current_page_item current-menu-item');`

Comment: @CaseyFalk, using jQuery is good, because if you use an other library on the future (like mootools), she using $ too. So created a conflic here

Comment: @Arthur: Fair point, Arthur! Overrides can happen with *anything* though -- so it boils down to "Ya' gotta know what you're using." If you're only using jQuery (as appears to be the case with the OP) then there is no reason to clutter the code so much. Edited the comment though to reflect your point. :)

Comment: Yes sure, just explain why somebody like to use jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need loop each item to do a remove class one by one, this is more easy :

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item').removeClass('current_page_item');
```

Or (it's the same) :

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
```

But I don't understand what is this 'this' :

```
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current_page_item');
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Do you mean :

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').addClass('current_page_item current-menu-item');
```

Or if you are on an event listener (like click, as @Daniel Sanchez feel on comment) you just need to do :

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').click(function(){   
  // Remove class on each item  
  jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');

  // Add class for this one    
  jQuery(this).addClass('current_page_item current-menu-item'); 
})
```

Comment: Its better to remove class once with space separated `removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');`

Comment: Yes i know but don't want give too much information at once ^^

Comment: if ops code is not working there is no reason for this to work

Comment: I have a feeling that this is in the context of a Click event, and OP has neglected to inform us of this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately your code made no difference. I've updated my original post to be a bit more specific.. I think I might have missed the point somewhere along the way.

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer, although the code doesn't work you did answer my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do but the code can be simplified somewhat:

```
jQuery("ul.menu li a").click(function(){
    jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item current-menu-item');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/re3hjzyf/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by replacing `this` with `'ul.menu li'`.

So the code would be like this

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').each(function() {
   jQuery('ul.menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item')
                       .removeClass('current_page_item');
});
// not sure what the following code is referencing too
// it is outside the bounds of .each() function.
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current_page_item');
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

### what is `this`

When working with JavaScript and many Object Oriented programming languages the `this` keyword is used to refer to the current context that the programmer is working with. You're currently referencing to the `ul.menu li` element so by using `this` you make a call to the element that is selected in the `.each()` function.

You can replace it by using the element selector that you used in the `each()` function.

Comment: No your code loop all item and remove class for ALL itemS

Comment: @Arthur, I have removed the ambiguity, :) I don't know what the last two lines are referencing too, so I didn't do it. I have just changed the `this` where it might refer to the code that is being used in the each function.

Comment: @BOSS, yes this would do the job, but I have commented that I don't know what the last two lines do.

Comment: @Arthur, oh were you talking about the class removal thing? :) I have edited it out. :) Thanks buddy!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Thanks Afzaal. As mentioned, I think I'm missing something outwith the scope of what I asked. I updated my question to advise what 'this' is.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
jQuery('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
```

Here I am making the assumption that only one item will ever have those classes as it would denote which menu item is currently selected. The best way to select it is then to search for the class you want to remove. (If those classes always go together, you could also remove both on the same line, although then you might want to consider whether you actually need both.

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').on("click", function() {
jQuery(this).addClass('current_page_item').addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```

You can only use "this" as an argument for the selector when "this" has a value (i.e : inside an each loop or inside on.
In this case I am using the on() function to apply the function which adds the class to any of the list items which gets clicked on.

Merging the two you would then end up with :

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').on("click", function() {
    jQuery('.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    jQuery('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    jQuery(this).addClass('current_page_item').addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```